# Таймер обновляется при переходе из одной формы в другую

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Таймер находится в label и работает при нажатии на кнопку. При переходе в другую форму и обратно, таймер обновляется и останавливается. Дебагом проверил, в самом label сохранилось, но в методе null. Где ошибка?

Код:

**UserControl.cs**

```
    #region FIELDS
    Timer timer;
    int seconds;
    #endregion
```

public UserContrElems()

```
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Interval = 1000;
        timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seconds++;
        labelTimer.Text = GetTime();
    }
```

**AdminForm.cs**

```
    private void MenuItemStore_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        AdminStoreForm store = new AdminStoreForm();
        store.ShowDialog();
    }
```

**AdminStoreForm.cs**

```
   private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        AdminForm admin = new AdminForm();
        admin.Show();
    }
```

И ещё, AdminForm открывается вначале через MainForm

**MainForm.cs**

```
   private void buttonOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Hide();
        AdminForm admin = new AdminForm();
        admin.Show();
    }
```

Comment: Какой таймер? Где?

Comment: как происходит переход между формами? где у вас инициализируется таймер?

Comment: таймер находится в юзер контроле. переход с помощью кнопки происходит

Comment: У вас точно Desktop? Код ну очень Web-приложение напоминает. В вебе по-другому.

Comment: точно десктопный, winforms.

Comment: @ИсмоилМухаммадиев я имею ввиду формы скрываются, уничтожаются или просто меняется фокус?

Comment: Подождите, оконный таймер привязан к окну - всё правильно, если вы окно закрываете - таймер уничтожается. Не привязывайте таймер к окну.

Comment: @yolosora когда первая форма открыта, вторая закрывается

Comment: @nick_n_a таймер в юзер контроле, а контроллер привязан к форму

Comment: в любом случае код который вы приложили не имеет никакого отношения к проблеме, приложите код создания таймера, код перехода между формами.

Comment: А форму закрываете - и таймер закрывается.... Всё верно для оконного таймера. Используйте другой тип таймера. Создайте скрытое окно именно для таймера. Возможно поможет создание таймера без контейнера т.е. `Timer/*ваше*/ = new Timer(null); Timer.Events += Timer_Tick();`

Comment: то что в label у вас осталось значение не говорит ничего о том, что "таймер остался", это просто последнее значение записанное по тику.

Comment: Ок, щась попробую переделать.

Comment: Ещё... вам нужен "глобальный" таймер. И правда  @yolosora прав, допустим таймер сохранился -  labelTimer - существует при форма закрыта - нет - будет или Exception, или данные пойдут на закрытую форму. С формой уничтожился и таймер привязаный к ней. Нужно 1)создать "глобальный" таймер, и 2)отвязать label что б не было описаного конфликта.